# C++ how to ignore specific characters when reading from a text file?

Tags: c++

i have a main function that reads a text file as such

```
int count = 0;
std::string fileName; 
std::fstream readFile;
std::string storeFile;
char myWord[50000];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file: " << std::endl; //prompts user for the filename
 std::cin >> argv[0];  //stores the filename is the first element of argv[]

fileName = argv[0];
readFile.open(fileName);

 if(!readFile) {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to open file " << std::endl;  //if the file cannot be opened an error is displayed
      exit(0); //if it cannot open the console terminates
      } else {
          std::cerr << "File successfully opened" << std::endl;
      }

      while(readFile >> storeFile){
          if(readFile.bad()) {
              std::cerr << "File failed to read " << std::endl;
              break; //loop terminates
                } else {
                   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myWord)/sizeof(myWord[0]); i++){
                                  readFile >> myWord[i]; 
                                  count++;
                } 
    }

    readFile.close();
```

An example of a snippet from the text file

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
```

How would i go about ignoring the puncuation when reading the file?(so igoring the symbols ' , : and .)

Comment: Simply remove the punctuation from each word, and ignore then-empty words? Did you try doing that? There is no built-in function in the C++ library that will do it for you. You will have to write the code to do that, yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the text file itself is massive, around 5000 words so i cant go and remove the puncuation individually if thats what you're sugguesting

Comment: Why not? What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik because thats extremely lengthy and inefficient

Comment: Why do you think that it's "extremely lengthy and inefficient"? I estimate this to be just two or three more lines of code. One line of code to remove all punctuation from `storeFile`, using `std::remove_if`, and `erase`; then `if (storeFile.empty()) continue;`. Why do you believe this will be any less efficient than any other approach?

Comment: @AdamWong *The text file itself is massive, around 5000 words* -- That is not massive.  As a matter of fact, that's tiny.

Answer (score 1):

You could read lines, replace punctation characters with spaces and then use istringstream and std::skipws to read words

Answer (score 0):

You can push to temporary char, then check it
`char c; readFile >> c; if (....) myWord[i] = c;`

Comment: `>>` is notorious for having poor performance in C++. It has to construct an exception handler, for example, for its duration. Doing this, for every character in the file, one at a time? Now ***that*** would be horrible performance.

Comment: I choose this because I think he need an easiest way (more like his code). Of course if we have performance problem, we have to take other way